# How to upload videos to Windows Media Services 2008

Tags: sharepoint, windows-media-services

Long time lurker, first time asker-of-questions.

We have Sharepoint 2010 running for our company intranet, and we want the ability to stream videos locally. SP2010 is awful for this.

I'm looking towards Windows Media Services 2008, a free download/addon for Windows Server 2008.

I've Googled and Googled, but I just cannot find anything which answers this:

**How do you actually upload the media to Windows Media Services 2008?**

Our IT department looks after the servers (and this is further complicated by being half-managed by a third party company). I need to know whether I will be able to upload media to WMS2008 over our network, like with a URL we can go to and click up (finding the file on our computer), rather than having to do it on the actual server itself.

I know this will sound like a daft question, but I just can't find the answer. Help me Stackoverflow, you're my only hope.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have already found answer to this question, but I am also working on Windows Media Services(WMS) 2008 for streaming videos and found your question while googling.
I have happened to manage to publish a video using WMS and view it on a client machine.

I'll quickly summarize the it for you. Basically you need to put your video file on the server, and then create a publishing point in WMS (using wizard or advanced mode)and use the mms URL to view video using Windows media player.

You can refer [this](https://araihan.wordpress.com/2009/12/15/windows-server-2008-install-and-configure-windows-media-services-2008step-by-step/) guide for configuring and streaming videos using WMS.

Please let me know if you need more details on this.
Hope this helps.